# How to add date original/suffix in custom JQuery?

Tags: javascript, string, date, var, suffix

I have the following Javascript that aim to revise the date format, however I would like to add date original or suffix such as *"st", "nd", "rd", "th"* to each end date number. For example, let's say our current date is set as **28 April** but I want to display date as **28th April**.

So if there is a possibility... how can you add this sample coding to the current javascript string?

```
var nth = function(d) {   if (d > 3 && d < 21) return 'th';   switch (d % 10) {
    case 1:  return "st";
    case 2:  return "nd";
    case 3:  return "rd";
    default: return "th";   } }
```

**Current JS:**

```
  // Blog date
    window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
    document.querySelectorAll('.waddons-blog-meta').forEach(el => el.textContent = formatDateString(el.textContent))
    }, false);
    function formatDateString(s) {
      var months = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"];
      var arr = s.split('/');
      return arr[1] + " " + months[arr[0] - 1];

      }
```

**Current HTML:**

```
<div class="waddons-blog-meta">3/7/2020 - </div>
```

Comment: `return arr[1] + nth(arr[1]) + " " + months[arr[0] - 1];`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply you can call the `nth` function in your code.

```
var nth = function (d) {
      if (d > 3 && d < 21) return 'th'; switch (d % 10) {
        case 1: return "st";
        case 2: return "nd";
        case 3: return "rd";
        default: return "th";
      }
    }

window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
  document.querySelectorAll('.waddons-blog-meta').forEach(el => el.textContent = formatDateString(el.textContent))
}, false);
function formatDateString(s) {
  var months = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"];
  var arr = s.split('/');
  return arr[1] + nth(arr[1]) + " " + months[arr[0] - 1];
}
```

If you want to superscript the `th` value, then use following code

```
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
  document.querySelectorAll('.waddons-blog-meta').forEach(el => el.innerHTML = formatDateString(el.textContent))
}, false);
function formatDateString(s) {
  var months = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"];
  var arr = s.split('/');
  return arr[1] + "<sup>" + nth(arr[1]) + "</sup>" + " " + months[arr[0] - 1];
}
```

Comment: First method worked successfully! Thank you for your support :)